# Firefox messages in /var/log/messages

Tags: firefox, log

I happened to be browsing through `/var/log/messages` for another reason, and I stumbled across some messages apparently related to Firefox like this:

```
Apr  5 15:36:59 myserver kernel: [18091.188462] type=1503 audit(1333658219.144:19):  operation="open" pid=6396 parent=1 profile="/usr/lib/firefox-11.0/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}" requested_mask="::r" denied_mask="::r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0 name="/shr/RiverTrip.gpx"
```

which are really puzzling me because I really don't see why Firefox would know about these files let alone output messages about them.

The `/shr` directory is an NTFS partition I set up on my laptop so I can access it with either Ubuntu or Windows XP.  The messages are consistently showing up for a few of the files in that directory, but not all.  I haven't even looked at those files or done anything else with them in a long time!  I have no idea what's special with those files; they appear to be picked at random as far as I can tell.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid), Kernel Linux 2.6.32-38, GNOME 2.30.2 and Firefox 11.0.  I hope someone can explain these spooky messages!

Comment: Hmm, apparently I can't officially answer my own question for 8 hours.  Short answer: It was AppArmor (and Shooter).  Long(er) answer: I'll post it when they let me.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the messages come from [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor), a "security module for the Linux kernel" which I never knew about before.  I'm still not quite sure why it gives me those messages, but it happens whenever I try to save a screenprint (I use the Shooter Firefox add-on) to the /shr directory.  Firefox doesn't let me, and pops up a Download Error window ("because you cannot change the contents of that folder") which I never really paid attention to.  I figured it was a permissions thing which I never bothered to look at or change since I was always satisfied with saving my screen print to another directory.

Anyways, I was able to test this and duplicate the messages.  By the way, I was wrong when I wrote that there were only a few files that were being reported on; actually I missed the fact that there were all these lines like `__ratelimit: 96 callbacks suppressed` which means that there were more messages that the system withheld from the messages file.

I still don't know the why AppArmor felt the need to report on every file in that directory...